# formula for getting combination of lists

Tags: math

I have

```
List 1 = AB
List 2 = CD
List 3 = EF
List 4 = GH
```

A program will print a final list composed by only one letter from each list.
So one of the combination can be
A
C
E
G

How many combination are possibile? What is the formula to count the number of the combinations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming as stated in the [help]. It may be a better fit on [math.se]: "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is just the product of the lengths of all your lists, so in your case: 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 = 16 combinations.